# Authentication in Golang WebSocket application

Tags: security, authentication, go, websocket, gorilla

I am trying to implement user authentication in an application that primarily uses WebSockets, but I am unsure how to begin.

I am using the Gorilla mux and websocket packages.

I have thought about using the method described [here](https://github.com/matryer/goblueprints/tree/master/chapter3/chat) (files main.go and auth.go), but does this approach secure against authenticated users somehow hijacking each others sockets like described in [this article](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/15/auth-with-socket-io/)?

Can someone suggest a good method or package(s) in Go?

Comment: @ThunderCat Ok, so it seems that I have misunderstood the article. Is it because it is specific to Socket.IO?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Authenticate as you would for a plain HTTP request before [upgrading](http://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Upgrader.Upgrade) the connection to the WebSocket protocol. Use whatever methods or packages you would use for plain HTTP requests.

A WebSocket connection can be hijacked to the extent that a plain HTTP connection can be hijacked. The WebSocket protocol does not introduce any new issues here.

Socket.io is a layer above WebSockets, long-polling and other techniques for sending events from the server to a browser client. Issues with Socket.io do not necessarily apply to direct use of a WebSocket.